# Research experience in SOP

Tags: graduate-admissions

At the moment, I have the following paragraphs solely about my research experience.

First paragraph describes the importance of the project. Second paragraph is about what has been done. Third paragraph describes what my lab is doing. Fourth paragraph is about my specific tasks in the lab and what I have learned.

Those paragraphs already take up more than a page. I am planning to use the remaining space for introduction and talking about why I want to attend this particular school. My concern is that I feel I discuss my research experience too much. Is it fine if my research experience is too detailed? Do you also have any suggestion about my approach to discussing research experience?

Comment: If only a quarter of the description of your research experience is about the work you carried out and what you learnt (i.e., your experiences), then that seems a little unbalanced.

Comment: I am just free writing at the moment, and I do find it is unbalanced. I am just not sure the readers would understand the project if I do not give sufficient background.

Comment: I suppose the thing to keep in mind is that the most important thing for the reader to understand is what you did. Maybe start by describing what you did, and then think about how much background would be necessary to understand what you've written. It may vary from field to field, and project to project, but I've often found that you don't need to say any more than a sentence or two about a project in order to convey the work you actually carried out (and why it's relevant to the application)

Comment: I don't understand why _what my lab is doing_ has anything to do with your future graduate school. If the lab is well known, the school you are applying would already know what it is doing. If the lab is unknown, why should your future school care?

Comment: More to say. The SoP is about you and what you want to do in the future, not about your current lab unless I misunderstood you. Are you talking about Statement of Purpose for your graduate school application?.

Comment: Yeah, I am writing my Statement of Purpose for this application cycle. My wording is kinda unclear. What I mean is my group is using a particular technology (CRISPR/Cas9) to do the project. I plan to explain why we use this technology since (again) I am not sure whether the readers would understand the project if I do not give sufficient explanation. I am actually performing this technology, so I have quite a lot to discuss about what I am doing.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I think I can assume the professors who are reading my SOP understand the background very well. OK, I will focus more on what I am doing and only provide explanation when necessary. I just started my SOP, so there are a lot of uncertainties. Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: That sounds like a good approach.  However, I want to reassure you that the explanations you include are also worthwhile in and of themselves, as they will demonstrate your effectiveness in writing about a project you're involved in.